# how to set the selected option using illuminate Form

Tags: php, html, laravel, formbuilder

I am using the `HtmlServiceProvider` in laravel 5.1 to  build my form ,  I want to set the selected option in select dropdown list  tag when I get the data from my model class

My code so far:

```
{!! Form::model($advertisment,['url'=>'dashboard/edit/advertisment']) !!}
{!! Form::select('Gender', [""=>'Select Gender',"Male"=>'Male', "Female"=>'Female'],0, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'form_control_6' ,'required']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to override the value from the model, pass in `null`

Answer (score 2):

Set the 0 parameter to "Male" for example and you will figure it out

Comment: how to get the value from the model ?

Comment: if the model is named Type for eg. then 
    $type = Type::find($id);
    $type->type, sure if you have such a column. The value must be one of the arrays key you provided in the select element